# anyone help ,how to display label.new values in a table using table.cell function

Tags: pine-script

condition used to genetate label.new below

display values using label.new function

```
if not na(pvtHighTemp) //and pvtLast  == 'L' 
                if pvtHighTemp > pvtHigh1Temp// or pvtHighTemp > pvtHigh1 
                    label.delete(tempHigh[1])
                    tradedVolume = f_getTradedVolume(profileLengthTemp, proceedTemp, pvtLengthTemp)
                 tempHigh := label.new(bar_index[pvtLengthTemp], pvtHighTemp, '* ' + (pvtPrice ? str.tostring(pvtHighTemp, format.mintick) :  '') + (pvtChange ? (pvtPrice ? ' ↑ %' : '↑ %') + str.tostring((pvtHighTemp - pvtLow1) * 100 / pvtLow1 , '#.##') : '') + (pvtVolume and  nzVolume ? (pvtPrice or pvtChange ? '\n' : '') + str.tostring(tradedVolume, format.volume) : ''), xloc.bar_index, yloc.price, #284aa9, label.style_label_down, color.white, (not pvtPrice and not pvtChange and not pvtVolume ? size.tiny : pvtTextSize), text.align_center, 'Temporary Pivot High : ' + str.tostring(pvtHighTemp, format.mintick) + '\n -Price Change : ↑ %' + str.tostring((pvtHighTemp - pvtLow1) * 100 / pvtLow1 , '#.##') + (nzVolume ? '\n -Traded Volume : ' + str.tostring(tradedVolume, format.volume)  + ' (' + str.tostring(profileLengthTemp - 1) + ' bars)\n  *Average Volume/Bar : ' + str.tostring(tradedVolume / (profileLengthTemp - 1), format.volume) : '') + '\n\nNumber of bars\n since last confirmed Pivot High/Low : ' + str.tostring(profileLengthTemp) 
    
    *
```

Answer (score 0):

The text in your label is constructed as below:

```
'* ' + (pvtPrice ? str.tostring(pvtHighTemp, format.mintick) :  '') + (pvtChange ? (pvtPrice ? ' ↑ %' : '↑ %') + str.tostring((pvtHighTemp - pvtLow1) * 100 / pvtLow1 , '#.##') : '') + (pvtVolume and  nzVolume ? (pvtPrice or pvtChange ? '\n' : '') + str.tostring(tradedVolume, format.volume) : '')
```

So, I would store that in a varibale and then pass it to `table.cell()`.

Something like below:

```
label_value = '* ' + (pvtPrice ? str.tostring(pvtHighTemp, format.mintick) :  '') + (pvtChange ? (pvtPrice ? ' ↑ %' : '↑ %') + str.tostring((pvtHighTemp - pvtLow1) * 100 / pvtLow1 , '#.##') : '') + (pvtVolume and  nzVolume ? (pvtPrice or pvtChange ? '\n' : '') + str.tostring(tradedVolume, format.volume) : '')

var testTable = table.new(position = position.top_right, columns = 1, rows = 1, bgcolor = color.yellow, border_width = 1)
if barstate.islast
    table.cell(table_id = testTable, column = 0, row = 0, text = "Label value: " + label_value)
```

Comment: iam getting error undeclared identifier "tradedvolume" in above code

Comment: OR it displyas NAN

Comment: Well, I just showed you how to do it. It's not a complete code. `tradedvolume` should be defined in your code.

Comment: Yes it's defined above in code check it, wen I use it in label_value it's shows error in that line undeclared traded volume